# Illegal instruction on pthread_mutex_lock()

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, instructions

I have a quite simple program running on Surface Pro 2 with Linux Mint 17.3. I have written multiple different programs with mutexes in C and until now I have not encountered any problem.

Now when the code reaches `pthread_mutex_lock()` function, it ends with "Invalid instruction". What does it even mean? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Could you run the program under gdb and disassemble `pthread_mutex_lock()`? Maybe the library is trying to use `TSX`- instructions.

Comment: Good chance that the mutex you attempted to unlock was either never initialized or no longer exists. Please show some code!

Comment: This may also occur when you try to lock the same mutex twice from the same thread. Show a [mcve] if you want to be helped.